# How to loop all the elements in the DB using RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I use this to loop the products...

```
<% form_for :product, @products, :url => { :action => "add_to_cart" } do |f| %>
<%= product.title %>
<%= product.price %>
<%= submit_tag 'Make Order' %>
<% end %>
```

In my DB, I have

```
product: 
title:abc price:874
title:cde price:98
title:efg price:18
```

but I can only get the efg 18.0 in my result, I miss other records on my result, 
any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you need an extra form for each product, (based on the `add_to_cart` action).
`form_for` helper generates a form for one object, so you will need to iterate through your objects and create a form for each one.

Something like that is probably what you need:

```
<% for product in @products %>
  <% form_for product, :url => { :action => "add_to_cart" } do |f| %>
    <%= product.title %>
    <%= product.price %>
    <%= f.submit 'Make Order' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It seems great, but I only want one "Make Order" submit button in my form, how can I do that?

Comment: How do you select the products to be added on your cart ? If you are adding these products dynamically into the form from ajax, then you should follow Can Berk Güder advice.

Comment: it's a question of style, but personally i would enumerate @products using the each enumerator method.

Answer (score 1):

`form_for` creates a form for a single object. If you want to create a form for multiple objects, I suggest you take a look at this question: [Multiple objects in a Rails form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form)