# Separating multiple models in Rails form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

Specifically, I have a form for creating a `User`. One of the fields is `Group`, which is a separate model. During the `User#create` action I call `Group.find_or_create_by_name` to check and see if the `Group` already exists by pulling out `params[:user][:group]`, and create the `Group` if it doesn't exist.

But, when I create the `User`, I can't pass `params[:user]`, because `params[:user][:group]` is not a group, it's a `String`. This would be a lot easier if I could supply `params[:user]` and `params[:group]` to my controller, instead of everything bundled under a single variable, but I don't know how to do that.

Relevant code:

User#create

```
@group = Group.find_or_create_by_name(params[:user][:group])
@group.save!
@user = @group.users.build(params[:user])
```

Partial User Schema

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name",                :default => "",    :null => false
  t.string   "email",                                  :null => false
  t.integer  "group_id"
```

Partial Group Schema

```
create_table "groups", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.text     "description"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
```

Params Dump from form submission

```
{"commit"=>"Register",
 "authenticity_token"=>"x1KgPdpJop5H2NldsPtk0+mBDtrmpM/oNABOxjpabIU=",
  "utf8"=>"âœ“",
  "user"=>{"name"=>"aName",
  "group"=>"aGroupName",
  "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "email"=>"anEmail"}}
```

The best explanation I've run across is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form) question.

I don't really want to start rearranging the `params` has inside of my controller as that really makes me queasy, and seems like terrible programming. Which really makes me question whether I've got a bigger problem.

If it goes against Rails conventions to do this, what then is the best way to do it, and why should I not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm going to spell out everything I've learned, in case other people are having trouble understanding this like I did. Also, if I get anything wrong here, please correct me.

If you're using a form that creates multiple model instances at once (preferably associated ones), you first need to use the helper `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model definition (probably right underneath your declared associations). The reason for this is it creates a setter method that knows how to write that type of associated model. (Note: you can also define this method yourself in your main model). Once you've done that you can nest a `fields_for` inside of a `form_for`, and Rails will know how to make the proper assignments.

I initially thought that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` was referring to nested resources, which is definitely not the case. If you're looking for more information, refer to section 11.8.3 (pp 343-347) of The Rails 3 Way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the proper way to do this here is to build the user off the group. That'd be appropriate if you were in an action of the `GroupsController` that, for example, added new users to a group. I think the best approach here would be to do the following:

```
@group = Group.find_or_create_by_name(params[:user][:group])
@group.save!
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.group_id = @group.id
@user.save
```

Since you're in the new action of the `UsersController`, it seems more fitting to be creating a new user instead of building it off an association and then adding that user to the group that either already existed or was just created.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that definitely makes sense. My bigger problem, however is that the `params[:user]` attributes do not reflect the matched attributes of a `User`, so trying `@user = User.new(params[:user])` fails. Specifically, `params[:user][:group]` is a `String`, not a `Group`. I could munge around the `params` hash in my controller and reassign it, but that sound terrible. How should I build my form to not include the `group` string as a part of `params[:user]`?

Comment: In hunting, it looks like I should be using `fields_for` while building my form. Still researching into this, I'll post a better answer once I've got it figured out.

Comment: Yeah, you should be using `fields_for` to add fields for attributes of another model. You'll also need to put `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model.

Comment: Yeah, I _think_ I've got most of this understood now. Thanks for all the help, Logan.