# ruby on rails - update multiple records of one model and its association in same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-associations

I have a form that enables a user to update multiple alert rules records at the same time. But each alert rule record can have many notification emails. So I would like to be able to update alert rules and the associated notification emails within the same form.

Models:

```
class AlertRule < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :notification_emails, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :notification_emails, :reject_if => lambda { |notification| notification[:email].blank? }
end

class NotificationEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :alert_rule
end
```

In one of my controllers, I send an array of alerts to a form:

```
  def alerts_config

      //more code
      @alert_rules = alert_rules.flatten
      @alert_rules.each { |a| a.notification_emails.build }

      render :partial => 'home/alerts_config', :layout => false
  else
```

Then in my form, I want to allow the user to update alert rules and the associated email notifications:

```
    = form_for @alert_rules, :url => '/home/save_alerts_config/' + @unit.id.to_s, :remote => true, :class => 'ajaxForm' do |f|
  %table.scrollTable{:cellspacing => "0", :width => "740px", :style => "border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;"}
    %thead.fixedHeader
      %tr
        %th Alerts
        %th Enable
        %th Primary Email
        %th Notification Emails
        %th
    %tbody.scrollContent
      - for rule in @alert_rules
        %tr
          %td= rule.alert_code.name
          %td= check_box_tag "enabled_ids[]", rule.id
          %td= f.text_field :email, :value => rule.email, :index => rule.id
          %td.fields
            = f.fields_for :notification_emails, rule.notification_emails do |notification_builder|
              = notification_builder.text_field :email
              = notification_builder.hidden_field :_destroy              
              = link_to_function 'Remove Notification', 'remove_notifications(this)'
  .save_panel
    = submit_tag "Save", :class => 'submit myButton'
```

When I submit to server, this is what I get:

```
Started POST "/home/save_alerts_config/6243" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-20 17:49:06 -0400
  Processing by HomeController#save_alerts_config as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NPwuKuWippYjm2tJcfQI+/x9oEBwcR2rxcfpZMTO/Qo=", "enabled_ids"=>["51"], "alert_rule"=>{"51"=>{"email"=>"hythy"}, "notification_emails_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"rtyrytry", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "2"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "3"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "4"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "5"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "6"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "7"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "8"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "9"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "10"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "11"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "12"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "13"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "14"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "15"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "16"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "17"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "18"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "19"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "20"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "21"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "22"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "23"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "24"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "25"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "26"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "27"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "28"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "29"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "30"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "31"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "32"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "33"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "34"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "35"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "36"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "37"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "38"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "39"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "40"=>{"email"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "52"=>{"email"=>"yutu"}, "53"=>{"email"=>"ytuytu"}, "54"=>{"email"=>""}, "55"=>{"email"=>""}, "56"=>{"email"=>""}, "57"=>{"email"=>""}, "58"=>{"email"=>""}, "59"=>{"email"=>""}, "60"=>{"email"=>""}, "61"=>{"email"=>""}, "62"=>{"email"=>""}, "63"=>{"email"=>""}, "64"=>{"email"=>""}, "65"=>{"email"=>""}, "66"=>{"email"=>""}, "67"=>{"email"=>""}, "68"=>{"email"=>""}, "69"=>{"email"=>""}, "70"=>{"email"=>""}, "71"=>{"email"=>""}, "72"=>{"email"=>""}, "73"=>{"email"=>""}, "74"=>{"email"=>""}, "75"=>{"email"=>""}, "76"=>{"email"=>""}, "77"=>{"email"=>""}, "78"=>{"email"=>""}, "79"=>{"email"=>""}, "80"=>{"email"=>""}, "81"=>{"email"=>""}, "82"=>{"email"=>""}, "83"=>{"email"=>""}, "84"=>{"email"=>""}, "85"=>{"email"=>""}, "86"=>{"email"=>""}, "87"=>{"email"=>""}, "88"=>{"email"=>""}, "89"=>{"email"=>""}, "90"=>{"email"=>""}, "91"=>{"email"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"6243"}
```

This shouldnt be. As I show in the controller above, I only build one notification per alert, so why it sends all the notifications back as if they are all associated with the first alert, when I check the first alert only, is beyond me.

update:
even when I used create! instead of build to actually write the associated record, it still presented same problem: unable to get the alert id inside the name attribute of the notification_email input field

Thanks for response

Comment: `fields_for` expects a collection object. When you call `all` you're feeding it an `Array`. What happens if you take the `all` off the call? So it looks like `, rule.notification_emails do`

Comment: @Azolo I initially tried doing that but it gave me the same exact error message "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email' for []:Array):"

Comment: I figured it wasn't that easy, I wonder what you're getting there instead. What does `= notification_builder.object.to_s` give you?

Comment: @Azolo When I add both arguments: f.fields_for :notification_emails, rule.notification_emails notification_builder.object.to_s will return [#<NotificationEmail id: nil, email: nil, alert_rule_id: 51, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>] and when I dont pass the second argument: f.fields_for :notification_emails, notification_builder.object.to_s will return an empty string. And when I use .all it gives me  an empty array: []

Comment: Maybe it has soething to do with fact that email notifications is not really an association yet (since i used build)n and so accepted_nested_attributes_for wont work: 1.9.2p290 :001 > AlertRule.first.notification_emails.build
 => #<NotificationEmail id: nil, email: nil, alert_rule_id: 73, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.2p290 :002 > AlertRule.first.notification_emails
 => []

Comment: I think you're half right, but it's also the `form_for "alert_rules[]"` I think.

Comment: Im going to update my question with what I get back when i use @alert_rules rather than "alert_rules[]"

Comment: I added this to alert rule model:   def notification_emails_attributes=(attributes)
      logger.info "What is going on with this: #{attributes}"
  end  but it doesnt get called or anything

Comment: I think I have it figured out. If you can post your old code up there too. Just as a reference for anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to like it. But this is what I did to make it work...

Information based on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form) and was heavily influenced by [this pretty awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/973201/527152) I can up with this:

**models/alert_rules_set.rb**

```
# NOTICE: I'm not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base
class AlertRulesSet
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion

  attr_accessor :alert_rules

  def alert_rules_attributes=(attributes)
    # I'm tricking "fields_for" here.
    # This should never actually be called
    raise
  end

  # Strip fields_for indexes and return an array
  def self.alert_rules_from(collection_set_hash)
    collection_set_hash[:alert_rules_attributes].values
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def alerts_config
  //more code
  @alert_rules_set = AlertRulesSet.new
  @alert_rules_set = AlertRules.all # Or Whatever
  @alert_rules_set.alert_rules.each { |a| a.notification_emails.build }

  render :partial => 'home/alerts_config', :layout => false
end

def update_alerts_config
  @alert_rules = AlertRulesSet.alert_rules_from(params[:alert_rules_set])

  # Save Logic here
end
```

**Form**

```
= form_for @alert_rules_set, :url => '/home/save_alerts_config/' + @unit.id.to_s, :remote => true, :class => 'ajaxForm' do |f|
  %table.scrollTable{:cellspacing => "0", :width => "740px", :style => "border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;"}
  %thead.fixedHeader
    %tr
      %th Alerts
      %th Enable
      %th Primary Email
      %th Notification Emails
      %th
  %tbody.scrollContent
    = f.fields_for :alert_rules do |alert_rules_builder|
      %tr
        %td= rule.alert_code.name
        %td= check_box_tag "enabled_ids[]", rule.id
        %td= alert_rules_builder.text_field :email, 
                         :value => rule.email, :index => rule.id
        %td.fields
          = alert_rules_builder.fields_for :notification_emails do |notification_builder|
          = notification_builder.text_field :email
          = notification_builder.hidden_field :_destroy              
          = link_to_function 'Remove Notification',
                'remove_notifications(this)'.save_panel
= submit_tag "Save", :class => 'submit myButton'
```

Here's a link to a [git branch where I got it working](https://github.com/Azolo/Custom-Nested-Resource-URL-example/tree/edit_batch_with_association) with another app and the [commit compare](https://github.com/Azolo/Custom-Nested-Resource-URL-example/compare/edit_batch_with_association).

## This is crazy! What's going on?

So historically [ActionPack](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionpack) tended to be pretty tightly coupled to [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord). This isn't a good idea for several reasons, so starting with Rails 3.0 [ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel) was introduced. Unfortunately this is one of those cases that could probably be better.

### ActiveModel

*NOTE: Some of this is changing, specifically with [this Rails 4 commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3b822e91d1a6c4eab0064989bbd07aae3a6d0d08)*

So basically, I'm implementing the bare minimum to make this case work. Apart from the `extend` and `include` directives, the only thing that is necessary to make any other ActiveModel class play nice in this case seems to be `persisted?`.

As for everything else...

**`attr_accessor :alert_rules`**
This is just holding the `alert_rules` data. This is what `fields_for` is going to use to populate the fields with existing data.

**`alert_rules_attributes=(attributes)`**
This is kinda special. This is what `fields_for` checks for when it wants to know when to render a collection or not. Without this you will just get a single nested field(ie. `[alert_rule][notification_emails_attributes]`) instead of a collection of nested fields(ie. `[alert_rule][notification_emails_attributes][1]`).

**`self.alert_rules_from(collection_set_hash)`**
This is the more confusing part. So basically when you submit some nested attributes they're actually in a `Hash` with an index key.

```
nested_model_attributes = {
    "0"=>{"attribute"=>"This", "id"=>"0"},
    "1"=>{"attribute"=>"That"}
}
```

This method is a quick way to get rid of that and get usable data out ([This happens in ActiveRecord too](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8510a0bb5a8a65e4bc067ee5a7d98aae965b47a5/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L382)). I figured it would probably be easier to manipulate the data than try to do some saving magic in the `AlertRuleSet` class (but you could).

Comment: It looks good. Can you explain the purpose of self.users_from a little more, thanks.

Comment: Sorry! It was late last night, it's actually supposed to be alert_rules_from (for your specific case) but I guess I forgot to change it. But yeah I'll change it and explain why it's there.

Comment: This was a lot of fun to research, but I feel like I'm not explaining some vital piece of information that isn't as basic as I thought.