# Rails 3 - Create View to Insert Multiple Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have what seems like a simple query. I need to create a view that will accept multiple records based on a single model. In my case the model is Project, which has 1 foreign key (person) and 2 fields time, role. I need to create a view (form) to insert 5 roles.

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
 <% 5.times do |index|%>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :position %><br />
    <%= f.text_field "fields[#{index}][stime]" %>
  </div>

 <% end %>
 <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
 </div>  
<% end %>
```

I get an error message: undefined method `fields[0][stime]'

I do not think the railscasts for nested models is what I need.

How would I go about creating this?

EDIT: The Project model code is below:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :person
   attr_accessible :role, :stime
end
```

The Projects_Controller code for the new method is below:

```
def new
 @project = Project.new
end
```

Comment: Could you post the complete form? Sounds like a `Project` needs three attributes, `person_id`, `time` and `role`, yet there is only a single input for `stime`? Not clear what's going on here. Posting your `Project` model would also be helpful.

Comment: I have added the Project model. I created a view to display only one field as of now. I suppose that should not be an issue.

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: Your model shows `role` as a single attribute of `Project`, yet you call for inserting five roles. How? What is your intended result?

Comment: @Riateche I have added the controller code, it does not do anything specific. Do I need to specify that I need 5 roles in the controller?

Comment: @gg_s - While defining a project, I also want to create 5 roles within that project. Rather than entering them in 5 forms, I would like to capture them at once.

Comment: What type is `role`? (string? array?) Are you using serialization?

Comment: This task is not that easy. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form

Comment: @gg_s - It's a string. Am not using serialization.

Comment: @Riateche - Thanks. One option would be 2 use nested models and re-create my current Project model in order to include something like Project_lines?

Comment: @andyd You basically want several strings to be concatenated into one string and saved to the database? You will not end up with five discreet roles, but one large combined role which cannot be (easily) converted back into discreet roles. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're planning to make some 1-to-many relationship (`Product has_many :roles`).

Here's some advices.

First, take a look at the [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) method. You need to add it to your model to be able to perform mass-create.

Second, [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) is what you need to design nested forms.

I'll give you some example of mass-creating for a simple `Product has_many :line_items` case:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :line_items, [LineItem.new]*5 do |li_fields| %>
      <%= li_fields.text_field :quantity %>
      <%= li_fields.text_field :price %>
      <br>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create line items" %>
<% end %>
```

All you need is to write in you controller something like:

```
@product.update_attributes params[:product]
```

and 5 `line_items` will be created at once.

Don't forget to white-list *`association`*`_attributes` (see `params` in your logs to see it). But I think if you get the mass-assignment error you'll do it anyway :)

I hope it helps.

Comment: I thought this was the case also, but there appears to be no association, nor a `Role` class, nor a `roles` table. `role` is simply a string attribute of `Project`, by design I suppose. Normalizing `role` makes sense here, but I wonder if OP did it his way intentionally.

Comment: Thanks jdoe. I think, instead of roles, we can replace it with persons. So a Project has many persons. So nested forms is the way to go?

Comment: @andyd Yes, nested forms can handle this.

Comment: I think that has to be the way to go, else it might just get convoluted. I have used the following tutorial: [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) from Railscasts..