# Rails - Multiple entries for a single attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am making an app in Rails 4. I use Simple Form.

I have a profile model and a qualifications model.

The associations are:

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :profile
```

qualifications.rb

```
has_many :qualifications
```

I have a form in my profile views, which includes a part of a form from my qualifications view.

profiles#form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

              <div class="form-inputs">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="intpol2">
              Your professional qualifications
            </div>

              <%= render 'qualifications/form', f: f %>     

          </div>
```

Qualifications#form

```
<%= simple_fields_for :qualification do |f| %>

  <div class="form-inputs">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= f.input :title, :label => "Your award" %> 
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">


        </div>


    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <%= f.input :level,   collection: [ "Bachelor's degree", "Master's degree", "Ph.D", "Post Doctoral award"] %>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= f.input :year_earned, :label => "When did you graduate?", collection: (Date.today.year - 50)..(Date.today.year) %>
        </div>

  </div>
```

Users may have more than one degree. I want to add a field that is a button which says 'add another qualification' and then a new set of the qualification form fields is available.

I found this post which tries to do something slightly different.  I don't want 10 blank sets of the form field (it will make the form look too long).

[Creating multiple records for a model in a single view in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304370/creating-multiple-records-for-a-model-in-a-single-view-in-rails)

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be looking for a gem called [`cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon); you can also watch [this Railscast (`Nested forms`)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) which is woefully outdated but still explains the structure very well.

---

The pattern is very simple, but requires some extra parts:

> 1. Have an ajax button which calls the controller
> 2. The controller needs to return a form and built `fields_for`
> 3. You'll use JS to append the new `fields_for` to the original form

The biggest problem is the `id` of your new `fields_for` - new implementations of this pattern use [`child_index: Time.now.to_i`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for#512-Setting-child-index-while-using-nested-attributes-mass-assignment)

I've written about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436526/rails-accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-f-fields-for-and-ajax).

Here's a new version:

---

## Ajax

Firstly, you need an *"Add Qualification"* button, which links to your controller through ajax:

```
#app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="intpol2">Your professional qualifications</div>
         <%= render 'qualifications/form', f: f %>     
       </div>
    </div>
       <%= button_to "+", new_profile_path, method: :get %>
<% end %>
```

---

## Controller

This will go through the *new* controller method, which we should be able to manage to return the specific response for the ajax request:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html, only: :new
   def new
      @profile = Profile.new
      @profile.qualifications.build
      respond_with @profile #-> will invoke app/views/profiles/new.js.erb
   end
end
```

---

## Response

Once your `new.js.erb` has fired, we need to build the new HTML form, extract the `fields_for` and append it to your view:

```
#app/views/profiles/new.js.erb
var fields_for = $("<%=j render "profiles/form" %>").html(); //-> might need tweaking
$(fields_for).appendTo("#new_profile.form-inputs");
```

**child_index**

You should also change your `qualifications/form` to include the `child_index`:

```
#app/views/qualifications/form.html.erb
<%= simple_fields_for :qualifications, child_index: Time.now.to_i do ...
```

Child index is meant to denote the `index` of the `fields_for` elements. In our case (since we're making all new records), it doesn't matter. Using `Time.now.to_i` ensures a totally unique `id` each time.

---

Finally, you need to make sure you're calling:

```
 <%= simple_fields_for :qualifications ... %>
```

... *plural*

Comment: Hi Rich, Thanks very much for this. It's all really clear and helpful and makes a lot of sense. Before I use cocoon. I tried to follow your steps. The problem I have is where I want to edit the existing profile to add a new qualification, I get an error with the <%= button_to "+", new_profile_path, method: :get %>. If I change that to update, then do I need the controller action to be repeated in the update field, or does it somehow know to look for it in the new action?

Comment: I have reversed the steps above and tried using cocoon, but this:               <%= link_to_add_association 'Add a qualification', f: f,  partial: 'qualifications/qualification_fields' %>
gives an undefined  method `object' for #<Hash:0x007fe70a4b38d8>. I have no idea what that error means, but will ask a fresh question to seek help interpreting it.

Comment: Can you give me a link to a github repo? I'll take a look at it if that's okay

Comment: Hi, it's a private repo. I don't have the pw to add others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you have to use nested form. You have to try your link tutorial because I will use this too. For another tutorial you can use this as reference [nested_forms-rails-4.2](http://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/).

I hope this help you.