# Rails 4 - Polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have a profile model and an address model.

the Associations are:

profile.rb

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
```

address.rb

```
 belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

Address is a polymorphic model.

I have an address form which has:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@address) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :unit %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :street_number %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :street %>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :building %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :city %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :region %>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :zip %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :country, priority: [ "Australia", "New Zealand", "United Kingdom" ] %>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <%= f.input :main_address %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <%= f.input :project_offsite %>
                    </div>


                </div>



            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <%= f.button :submit, :class => "formsubmit" %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
```

I try to create an address and save it. I then check that it is in the rails console. Something is going wrong because the rails console shows this:

```
#<Address id: 1, unit: "", building: "", street_number: "34", street: "f", city: "sdfasdf", region: "asdf", zip: "2000", country: "GB", main_address: nil, project_offsite: nil, time_zone: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, addressable_id: nil, addressable_type: nil, created_at: "2015-12-30 00:07:00", updated_at: "2015-12-30 00:17:00">
```

The addressable id and the addressable type are both nil.

They should have the references back to profile or wherever the related model is.

Is there a step missing in setting up this process?

This video (minute 3.40) says rails automatically handles filling out the type and id fields for polymorphic models.
https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations?autoplay=1

When I try to create a new address from the rails console, I type:

```
Address.create(addressable: Address.first, profile_id: "1", country: "AU")
```

The console error is:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'profile_id' for Address
```

My address table has an addressable_id key and my profile model has has_many :addresses, as: :addressable

I can't understand what causes the error

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

So, from what I gather from the suggestions below, I need to do something to let address know that it belongs to a profile.

I also found this article which sets out an example of what needs to happen in the profiles controller to get things working with polymorphic associations:
http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2015/02/10/rails-polymorphic-models/

I change my new action in the profiles controller to (include addresses.build):

```
 def new
    @profile = Profile.new
    @profile.qualifications.build
    @profile.visions.build
    @profile.personalities.build
    @profile.addresses.build

    authorize @profile
  end
```

I add nested attributes to my address association in the profile model:

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

I change my address form:
-  from form_for to fields_for;
-  rename it _address_fields.html.erb; and 
- open the div tag with:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
```

In my profiles form, I add the link to the form partial:

```
              Your addresss
            </div>
            <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>

              <%= render 'addresses/address_fields', f: f %>  
            <% end %>
            </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

               <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an address', f, :addresses, partial: 'addresses/address_fields' %>

            </div>
```

All of this is as set out in Jeiwan's answer on this post: [Rails - Cocoon gem - Nested Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539157/rails-cocoon-gem-nested-forms)

Then, when I try all of this, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in ProfilesController#update
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_addresses_on_addressable_type_and_addressable_id" DETAIL: Key (addressable_type, addressable_id)=(0, 1) already exists. : INSERT INTO "addresses" ("unit", "building", "street_number", "street", "city", "region", "zip", "country", "addressable_id", "addressable_type", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"
```

The error points to the update method in the profiles controller:

```
 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
```

I found this post which describes a user's similar problem, but before i change the database, I'd like to try and understand what has happened.

[Rails auto-assigning id that already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068800/rails-auto-assigning-id-that-already-exists)

Another odd thing is when I look at the last address created in the console, it shows this:

```
#<Address id: 6, unit: "", building: "", street_number: "34", street: "asdf", city: "asdf", region: "add", zip: "2111", country: "AU", main_address: nil, project_offsite: nil, time_zone: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, addressable_id: 1, addressable_type: 0, created_at: "2016-01-01 22:01:31", updated_at: "2016-01-01 22:01:31">]>
```

The record now has an addressable_id but does not have an addressable_type. Is there something extra required to populate this field?

Answer (score 1):

This form does not have `addressable` id/type fields so unless you explicitly set them or related object in controller getting `nil` is what is expected.

Defining the relation in model only states that objects can be related in this way, but does not set actual values. Actually - rails has a lot of magic in it, but it cannot guess which `profile` is the owner of which address

Comment: but how do you set them?

Comment: @user2860931 just declare them as a  hidden or select for the addressable, or if you just be able to set it later leave as is, just skip validate addressable_id to nil.

Comment: but if the address form belongs to a profile, and the edit profile path leads to the address form, isn't that the link. If I let users select the id, then it will look very odd in the form if the user is asked to select their own profile id to add the address. None of the examples show a requirement for a hidden field to get this working. Please can you show me a link to an example of this? Thanks very much

Comment: This video says rails automatically handles filling out the polymorphic id fields https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations?autoplay=1

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused with [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

> With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association

This means that `ActiveRecord` will *automatically* assign the `addressable_type` & `addressableid` of the `Address` model, depending on which associated model created it.

For example...

```
#app/models/profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
end

#app/models/address.rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

The above means that each time you create a **profile**, you have the ability to create or assign addresses for it. If you had another model (`users`), you could do the same. The `addressable_id` & `addressable_type` will be assigned automatically on the `address` record:

```
#app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @profile = Profile.new profile_params
       @profile.save
   end

   private

   def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(...)
   end
end
```

--

The main problem you have is that you're getting confused between which model has the `polymorphic` element of the association.

> They should have the references back to profile or wherever the related model is.

```
@profile = Profile.find x
@address = @profile.addresses.new address_params ...
```

This will assign `addressable_id` and `addressable_type` for the `profile` model, allowing you to create addresses on behalf of the `profile`.

```
@address = current_user.addresses.new address_params
```

This exact same code would allow you to create an address for a *user* (same model, same associations etc).

---

To answer your question, you need to scope your object creation around the associated model:

```
@address = Address.create(country: "AU")

@profile = Profile.find 1
@profile.addresses << @address
```

You could also do:

```
@profile = Profile.find 1
@profile.addresses.create country: "AU"
```

--

If you wanted addresses to be "dependent" on others, you'd need to add a `parent_id` column, and use [`acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) or another hierarchy gem.

Comment: Hi Rich. Thanks for this. I'm not sure what you're suggesting for how to link address to profile. Do I need to add something to the profile controller new action to build the profile.address?  Looking at this line you set out above"@address = @profile.addresses.new address_params ..." - I'm not sure where to use this in my profile controller.  I can't find an example of this in any of the resources.

Comment: Im also confused by you're comment that I'm confused by which model has the polymorphic element of the association. I think I have the associations set up correctly - I can't see the difference between your example and my code