# Rails 4 - Polymorphic associations with update action on nested polymorphic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to figure out a problem I seem to keep having in setting up polymorphic associations in my Rails 4 app.

I have a project model and an address model. The associations are:

Profile

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Address

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

I previously asked this question on the same problem. I couldn't (and still can't) understand the answers in that post: [Rails 4 - Polymorphic associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552688/rails-4-polymorphic-associations)

This time around - I'm having a problem that is triggered when I try to update a profile by inserting an address. The error message identifies the problem as coming from the update action in the profiles controller. The update action has:

My profiles controller update action has:

```
def update

    # successful = @profile.update(profile_params)

    # Rails.logger.info "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    # Rails.logger.info successful.inspect
    # user=@profile.user
    # user.update.avatar
    # Rails.logger.info "prof xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    # Rails.logger.info @profile.update(profile_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update(profile_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error message says:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_addresses_on_addressable_type_and_addressable_id"
DETAIL:  Key (addressable_type, addressable_id)=(Profile, 1) already exists.
```

Does anyone know what this message means, and how to address it?

Comment: This is a PSQL error, it means that there is already an entry in the database with addresable_type as "Profile" and addressable_id as "1". So, this means that you are creating a new Addressable in your update action.

Comment: Do you know how i could make it into an update on the existing record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database, you have set a unique constraint: , you can go to the database to see what you have set by the name of "index_addresses_on_addressable_type_and_addressable_id". As the error message show, you try to update a record with value ( Profile , 1) which has already been used by another record.
To solve this issue, there are two solutions: 
one is from the database side:
you need to know why there is a unique constraint about addresses. if it is not need , you can remove it from the database.
the other is ensure the (addressable_type, addressable_id) is unique before you update your data into database.

hope this can give a kind of help

Comment: Thanks @Eric - I can't think why i made the index value unique   add_index "addresses", ["addressable_type", "addressable_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_addressable_type_and_addressable_id", unique: true, using: :tree
I'll try and find out why I did that and then your solution sounds great. Thanks!