# How to add multiple rows in a single table using single submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new to Ruby on Rails and don't know much about it. I want to add `attribute_id` and `attribute_value_id` from table `Attribute` and `AttirbuteValue` to third table `CustomerOrder (id, attribute_id, attribute_value_id)`. A user can have multiple combination of `attribute_id` and `attribute_value_id`. I am looping all values of `Attribute` and `AttributeValue` to a `customerOrder` from and want to save all checked values to `CustomerOrder` table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multiple records for a model in a single view in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304370/creating-multiple-records-for-a-model-in-a-single-view-in-rails)

Comment: @BilalMaqsood thanks. this is some what similar to what I am trying to achieve. I will try to code according to this.