# How to get multiple records created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following create method:

```
def new
   @stores = Store.where(:store_id => @store.id)
   @product = Product.new(id: @store.id)
end

def create

   @product = Product.new(product_params)
   @product.store_id = params["store_id"]

   if @product.save
     redirect_to table_products_path, notice: 'product was successfully created.' 
   else
     render action: 'new'
   end

end
```

and a form that looks like:

```
<%= form_for [@table, @product] do |f| %>

  <% @stores.each do |store| %>
     <%= hidden_field_tag :store_id, store.id %>
     <%= f.label :product_price %><br>
     <%= f.text_field :product_price %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

and the models:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table
  has_many :products

end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
end
```

Basically, for each store there is, I want a product to be created. Right now, the only product_price that gets saved is the last one. So for example, if there are three stores, and I enter in the product_price text fields for each one, it only saves the last.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Where are you getting `@table` and `@stores` from?  Can you post that code including the association between the models.

Comment: Sure I just posted it.

Comment: what about `@table`, where is that defined?

Comment: I have a `before_action set_table` that takes a param from the url and assigns it to `@table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding your form fields by having multiple `product_price` and `store_id` inputs. Browser sends only the last one.
Check out this question: [Multiple objects in a Rails form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form)

Once you're done with that, change your controller action to something like this:

```
Store.where(:store_id => @store.id).each do |store|
  Product.create(params[store.id][:product])
end
```

Hope you get the idea.