# Submitting multiple objects of one class on one form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, fields-for

I'm still hazy on what is the first parameter for `form_for` or `form_tag` and which one to use when.  But basically I'm building a website where visitors can post concert events to the site. **Event** is a model.  The admin can see a list of submitted events and I want each one to have a check box and then the admin can check which events he wants to approve and hit submit on the form and they all get updated. `:approved` is a boolean field in the **Event** model.

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form) but am not sure where they get the first parameter in for `form_tag` in the next to last answer.

I figured I need a new controller called EventsUpdateController.  So far I have something like this but it's not quite right:

```
<%= form_tag events_update_path do  %>
  <% @unapproved_events.each do |event| %>
    <%= fields_for "events[]", event do |e| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= e.check_box :approved %></td>
        <td><%= event.date.strftime('%A %B %-d') %></td>
        <td><%= event.time.strftime('%l:%M %P') %></td>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `check_box_tag`

```
<%= form_tag events_update_path do  %>
  <% @unapproved_events.each do |event| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "event_ids[]", event.id, :id => "event-#{event.id}" %></td>
      <td><%= event.date.strftime('%A %B %-d') %></td>
      <td><%= event.time.strftime('%l:%M %P') %></td>
      <td><%= event.title %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag "Approve" %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller action,

```
events_to_approve = Event.find(params[:event_ids])
```

Comment: This code produces the following (with the same id for each event): <input id="event_ids_" name="event_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="10" />

Comment: You can set the id manually. But name is what is important for params