# Ruby on Rails - Form for multiple new Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a backend(Namespace admin) and want to create 4 new database entries with 1 form submit(4 new countries). What I got so far:

In my countries_controller.rb

```
class Admin::CountriesController < Admin::AdminController
    def new
      @countries = Array.new(4) { Country.new }
    end

end
```

In my new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @countries] do |f| %>   
  <% @countries.each do |country| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <%=f.text_field :country, :name, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Country 1" %><br>
        <%=f.text_field :country, :iso, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "us" %>
      </div></div></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But that doesn't work and I get a `undefined method model_name for Array:Class` error. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form_for` is for a single ActiveRecord object, but you're using it with an Array of object :

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @countries] do |f| %>
```

Either create a form per object (with each form a save button):

```
<% @countries.each do |country| %>
  <%= form_for [:admin, country] do |f| %>   
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or see this question for a solution using only one form: [Multiple objects in a Rails form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972857/multiple-objects-in-a-rails-form)

Comment: How do I do this if I do not have the size of the array?